# How to change the background color of PointCloudLayer in Deck.gl

Tags: background, deck.gl

I created an application with PointCloudLayer, which is very similar to the example here:
[Deck.gl official example](https://deck.gl/examples/point-cloud-layer/)

The source code of this example can be found from this URL: [source code of this example](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/website/point-cloud/app.js)

I didn't specify the background color, but it seems PointCloudLayer uses the background color like this example as default.  How can I change the background color of PointCloudLayer?

Comment: Have you tried to change clearColor [here](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/0afd4e99a6199aeec979989e0c361c97e6c17a16/examples/website/point-cloud/app.js#L99)?

Comment: I was stupid to miss that parameter. Changing clearColor indeed changes the background color. Thank you so much. Appreciated.

Comment: Le met add it as answer so you can accept it for future reference to others users.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are refering to clearColor parameter. As you can see in the same link you provide, at [row 98 and 99](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/blob/0afd4e99a6199aeec979989e0c361c97e6c17a16/examples/website/point-cloud/app.js#L99) is `[0.93, 0.86, 0.81, 1]`. Change it with what you want but pay attention: values are clamped to the range 0-1.

```
<DeckGL
 ...
  parameters={{
    clearColor: [0.93, 0.86, 0.81, 1]
  }}
/>
```

You can read more about parameters properties of Deck.GL [here](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/deck#parameters) and more info about what kind of parameters you can use from luma official documentation [here](https://luma.gl/docs/api-reference/gltools/parameter-setting), in particular about `clearColor` [here](https://luma.gl/docs/api-reference/gltools/parameter-setting#clear-color).